# Problem 4.37 from Griffiths electrodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, dielectric, dipole

The problem says :

> "A point dipole p is imbedded at the center of a sphere of linear
> dielectric material (with radius $R$ and dielectric constant k). Find the electric potential inside and outside the sphere."

Do I have to use the superposition principle for the dipole potential and that of the rest of the dielectric? Or should I assume an infinitesimal sphere around the dipole and solve for the rest of the sphere in the volume between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think none of the two captures the key to solving the problem. If you want to add potential of dipole and that of the rest dielectric part, how are you going to calculate the later? You will probably still have to solve the Laplace equation $\nabla^2 V(r,\theta) = 0$ with boundary conditions.

So what are the boundary condition? Since you are reading Griffiths, I am sure that you must have seen the following equations in other examples.
\begin{align}
& \lim_{r \rightarrow R^+}{V(r,\theta)} = \lim_{r \rightarrow R^-}{V(r,\theta)} \\
& {\partial V(r,\theta) \over \partial r}\big|_{r \rightarrow R^+} - {\partial V(r,\theta) \over \partial r}\big|_{r \rightarrow R^-} = {-\sigma_b(\theta) \over \varepsilon_0}
\end{align}
The first equation tells you the potential is continuous at $R$, and the second tells you the electric field is discontinuous at $R$ since there is the bound charge $\sigma_b(\theta)$. Since the material is dielectric,
$$\sigma_b(\theta) = \varepsilon_0(k-1)\vec{E}(r,\theta)\big|_{r \rightarrow R^-} \cdot \hat{r} = -\varepsilon_0(k-1){\partial V(r,\theta) \over \partial r}\big|_{r \rightarrow R^-} $$
Therefore, given $V(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}{{B_l \over r^{l+1}}P_l(\cos{\theta})}$ when $r>R$ and $V(r,\theta)={p\cos{\theta} \over 4\pi k\varepsilon_0 r^2} + \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}{A_lr^lP_l(\cos{\theta})}$ when $r<R$, we have
\begin{align}
& B_0 = A_0 = 0 \\
& {B_1 \over R^2}={p \over 4\pi k\varepsilon_0 R^2} + A_1R\\
& {B_l \over R^{l+1}}=A_lR^l, \ l>1
\end{align}
by the continuity of $V$ at $R$. We derive these equations through multiplying $P_{l'}(\cos{\theta})\sin{\theta}d\theta$ on both sides and integrate over $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$), and
\begin{align}
& -\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}{(l+1){B_l \over R^{l+2}}P_l(\cos{\theta})} + {p\cos{\theta} \over 2\pi k\varepsilon_0 R^3} - \sum_{l=1}^{+\infty}{lA_lR^{l-1}P_l(\cos{\theta})} = {-\sigma_b({\theta}) \over \varepsilon_0} \\
& = (k-1)\bigg(-{p\cos{\theta} \over 4\pi k\varepsilon_0 R^3} + \sum_{l=1}^{+\infty}{lA_lR^{l-1}P_l(\cos{\theta})}\bigg)
\end{align}
Similar to how we compute the equations which $A_l$'s and $B_l$'s have to satisfy for the continuity of $V$, this time we have
\begin{align}
-2{B_1 \over R^2}+{p \over 2\pi k\varepsilon_0 R^3}-A_1 & = (k-1)\bigg(-{p \over 2\pi k\varepsilon_0 R^3}+A_1\bigg) \\
-(l+1){B_l \over R^{l+2}}-lA_lR^{l-1} & = (k-1)lA_lR^{l-1}, \ l>1
\end{align}
Solving these equations, we get $A_1={(k-1)p \over 2\pi \varepsilon_0 R^3k(k+2)}$ and $B_1={3p \over 4\pi \varepsilon_0(k+2)}$, and $A_l=B_l=0$ for $l>1$. Therefore, when $r>R$,
$$V(r,\theta)={p\cos{\theta} \over 4\pi \varepsilon_0 r^2}\big({3 \over k+2}\big)$$
and when $r<R$,
$$V(r,\theta)={p\cos{\theta} \over 4\pi k\varepsilon_0 r^2}\big(1+2{r^3 \over R^3}\big({{k-1} \over {k+2}}\big)\big)$$